# Increasing a value when use socket - JS

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I work on a notification system and i would like to put a number equivalent to the number of notifications i have. 
I use socket.io to send the notification.

I already test to declare var outside of the function

my code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();
var i = 0;

socket.on('libCourtLotChangeServ', function(contrat){
    $( "#notifBar" ).append( '<div class="innerNotif" style="width: 96%; height: 30px; text-align: left; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; padding: 3px;">' + 'Le contrat ' + contrat + ' a été modifié' + '</div>');
     function increase(n){
        n++;
        return n;
     }; i = increase(i);
     document.getElementById("notificationNumber").innerHTML = i;
     })
</script>
```

Comment: Put a `console.log` after `var i = 0;` to see if your `<script>` getting called only once

Comment: i put the console.log(i) but nothing append on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();
var i = 0;

// Step 1: add a console.log here and make sure its printed in the console when page loads
console.log(i);

socket.on('libCourtLotChangeServ', function(contrat){
    //Step 2: add a console.log here and make sure subscriber works  
    console.log(contrat);     

    $( "#notifBar" ).append( '<div class="innerNotif" style="width: 96%; height: 30px; text-align: left; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; padding: 3px;">' + 'Le contrat ' + contrat + ' a été modifié' + '</div>');

    //Step 3: Increment i
    i++;

    //Step 4: Make sure notificationNumber is the ID of the div 
    //Step 5: use jquery to add value inside `notificationNumber` div  
    $("#notificationNumber").html(i); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. i is equal to 1on the console and is equal to 2 on the html and doesn't change after

Comment: i change the name of the var and it works ! Maybe "i" was already use